# Why am I unable to assign a value to a form field on submit?

Tags: django

I have a model field called nearbyzips1, and I have a list of integers called in zip_codes.  I am trying to pass the value of zip_codes[1] to nearbyzips1, but for some reason it won't save.  When I fill out the form and hit submit, I can see all the values from each field except for nearbyzips1 which returns None.

```
if form.is_valid():

    cleanzipcode= form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
    nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code=cleanzipcode).location).order_by('distance')[:8]

    zip_codes = list(nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))
    //print zip_codes
    form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips1'] = zip_codes[1]
    //print form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips1']
    profile = form.save()
```

I added some print statements to troubleshoot, and zip_codes prints a short list of integers as expected.  form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] returns one of those integers from the list.  So then why is it not saving?  I am very confused.

I am suspecting the issue is in the code above, but just in case I have included some of my other code from forms.py and models.py in case it helps.

models.py

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    streetaddress=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                       max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips1=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Base form used for fields that are always required """
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                                 max_length=30,
                                 required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Put the first and last name at the top
        new_order = self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]
        new_order.insert(0, 'first_name')
        new_order.insert(1, 'last_name')
        self.fields.keyOrder = new_order

    class Meta:
        model = get_profile_model()
        exclude = ['user', 'privacy']
        widgets = {
            'deliveryoption': forms.RadioSelect(choices=[
            (True, '  Yes'),
            (False, '  No')             
        ])}


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        profile = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        # Save first and last name
        user = profile.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        user.save()

        return profile
```

Should I maybe try pass the value to nearbyzips1 from inside the forms.py rather than the views.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
# --- Replace this ---
# form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips1'] = zip_codes[1]
# print form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips1']
# profile = form.save()
# --- whith this ---
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.nearbyzips1 = zip_codes[1]
profile.save()
```

I really don't like to place business logic into `ModelForm.save`, prefer to place all business logic into the view.

Comment: Okay, is there a difference between passing the value to nearbyzip1 inside views.py or forms.py?

Comment: Not really, but then you should not mess with `form.cleaned_data` outside the `form.clean` method - I mean, move the zip_codes logic into the `form.clean` method.